# JSON Convert not working as expected

Tags: javascript, json, visual-studio-2010

I have a JSON string called EmployeeList being passed back to my webpage.  It is details being read in C# from an XML file.  SO it contains details for two test employees.

it is below:

```
"[{"EmployeeId":"33","Name":"Test Name 1","Phone":"1234","Email":"test@hotmail.com"},{"EmployeeId":"31","Name":"Test Name 2","Phone":"1234","Email":"test2@hotmail.com"}]"
```

I wanted to use the below then to turn this into a Javscript object so that I can extract and maniuplate fields.

```
        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(EmployeeList);

        alert(obj);
```

However my output from the alert is [object Object],[object Object].  Is there something I am missing or doing wrong here?

Comment: Nothing wrong here. The two objects are each of the employees. Try alert(obj[0].Name) instead.

Comment: alert converts the objects to string, therefore it just writes out the data type.
Use console.log(obj) and check the result with Firebug or your favourite web inspector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct response as your List is an Array of Objects.

To get name of employees you can get them like this:

```
alert(EmployeeList[0].Name);
alert(EmployeeList[1].Name);
```

Comment: You could use Internet Explorer - Developer Tools (F12) or FireBug to test this yourselves.

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin for jQuery, which displays an object in a readable format: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Dump

Also, if you're satisfied with **console.log()** command, you can use it to debug the object's value.

Answer (score 0):

... rather than alert(obj), try console.dir(obj) (if you're using FF/firebug that is)